# C# XNA Enter Houses

Tags: c#, xna, playback, role

I'm making a role playing game in C# using XNA. I already have a map and some stuff, but that's not interesting at the moment. My question is: How can I give the player the possibility to enter houses or rooms?

To create the worlds, I've used standard int-arrays where each number represents a different type of tile. That works all fine, but the house isn't enterable but a solid textured block of something.

BTW I've used a Vector3 to determine in which world the player's currently located and which one the program must load next.

Any suggestions how I can make the houses enterable?

Comment: rectangle trigger in front of doors that will trigger when you step on it... then you can give option to enter or continue wandering.

Answer (score 1):

One easy way to make houses enterable is to create a trigger object at the door of the house.
This object can be a simple Rect along with an id.

While the player moves around your map check for a collision between the player and the trigger.

When the player enters this trigger you can change the displayed map with a new one (the interior of the house) and move the player where the door should lead.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using C# to make a game, you might want to consider switching to MonoGame (which is practically XNA's successor since XNA is dead) or Unity.

As mentioned previously, your best option in XNA is to create a Rectangle which will trigger on collision and change the game world.

Comment: Thanks for the information with MonoGame, I've just downloaded it ;)